# OB Start before Session Start to Avoid Header Already Sent Error in PHP?

Tags: php

To avoid 'headers already sent' error message can I use obstart before session start in PHP, like below:

```
// db information here
ob_start();
session_start();
```

Is this a good practice to use in every PHP project to avoid 'header already sent error' or it is for special cases?

Comment: Nope, to avoid the error - just don't send anything before starting session. In programming (and in life as well) it makes sense to fix the roots of the issue, not the consequences

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a good practice.

The only correct solution - is to not send anything before you run session.

It's not for special cases, it's for people who cannot write properly. Treat it as a dirty hack for newbies.